# PHP - Echoing a specific string from an array which is result of a function

Tags: php, function

PHP:

I have made up a function that returns an array. I would like to be able to echo only one part of this array without having to make a variable like this:

```
$var = meth_0('getPlayerLimit');
echo $var['success'];
```

Is this possible? I´ve already tested doing what's bellow and it didn´t work.

```
echo meth_0('getPlayerLimit')['success'];
```

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: no this is not possible, you can use print_r() for verification

Comment: @MoyedAnsari False, see answers below, it is entirely possible ;)

Comment: @NishuTayal 'meth_0' is the name of the function.

Comment: I´ve seen both answers. I understand now. I couldn´t make it work because i´m using PHP Version 5.3.8. I will update :) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `PHP 5.4`, it is called array dereferencing:

```
  function get_cars()
  {
    return ["ferrari","lamborghini","maserati","bugatti"];
  }
  echo get_cars()[3];  //bugatti
```

example taken at http://www.waynemay.com/function-array-dereferencing-in-php-5-4-03052012

Answer (score 4):

It is possible only with php 5.4 and this is called Array Dereferencing, newly added to php.

On another note, you have ways with php 5.3 and less to do this such as:

```
echo reset(meth_0('getPlayerLimit')); //Success must be first item
echo end(meth_0('getPlayerLimit')); //Success must be last item
```

or

```
echo valueOf(meth_0('getPlayerLimit'), 'success');
function valueOf($arr, $idx){ return $arr[$idx]; }
```

Thats all i can think of!